# MySQL Find Average Timediff of with group By And Exclusion

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which contains two datetime columns:

```
CREATE TABLE test (job_id int, dateCol1 DATETIME, datecol2 DATETIME);
```

It contains a series of data representing the start and end times of jobs. I need to know what is the Average duration of those jobs in minutes, but so far can't see how to achieve it.

I have tried various things:

```
SELECT job_id, AVG(TIMEDIFF(datecol2,datecol1)) FROM test GROUP BY job_id;
SELECT job_id, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMEDIFF(datecol2,datecol1))) FROM test  GROUP BY job_id;
SELECT job_id, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(datecol2)-TIME_TO_SEC(datecol1))) FROM test GROUP BY job_id;
SELECT job_id, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol1))))) FROM test GROUP BY job_id;;
```

I'm comparing it to a list of all jobs which I printed out and Averaged in Excel, but so far I am getting different results.

As an addition I will also need to exclude any where the duration is greater than 1 hour.

I'm sure I am just overcomplicating this, and if someone can show me the way it would be appreciated, otherwise Ill end up having to print out a list for each jobid, and averaging them manually in excel.

Comment: Are there multipe records in this table for each job_id, or does each job_id only have a single record? Are you trying to get the average of all job_ids?

Comment: Sorry, each job_id has multiple entries, and there are apx 100 job_id's. I'm after the average,for each job_id.

Comment: As far as teh exclusion goes, do you want to exclude the job id's which AVERAGE more than an hour or do you want to exclude any individual records with time difference greater than an hour from being included in the calculation of averages?

Comment: I need to exclude anything where datecol2-datecol1 is greater than 1 hour, and then average whatever is left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to get the seconds difference and then get the average.

```
SELECT job_id, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol1))) 
FROM test 
GROUP BY job_id;
```

If you need to filter those with a higher difference than an hour...

```
SELECT job_id, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol1))) 
FROM test 
WHERE  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecol1) < 3600 
GROUP BY job_id;
```

Br

Comment: I think my problem was comparing with Excel, and not concentrating on whether the SQL looked right. Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The follow query will exclude Job runs that are greater than 1 hour

```
SELECT  job_id
        ,AVG(TIMEDIFF(datecol2,datecol1)) 
FROM    test
WHERE   datecol2 < DATE_ADD(datecol1, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY
        job_id;
```